# Foundation CSS not working in MVC5 Web Application

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2017, zurb-foundation

I have created an MVC Web project and added foundation-sites, but cannot get the css styles to work.

I have created an ASP.Net Web MVC Web application project using Visual Studio.
I have added the nuget package Foundation-Sites 6.5.3
I have removed BootStrap nuget package, and removed references from bundles.config and _Layout.cshtml
I have added references to foundation scripts and css in bundles.config and _layout.cshtml
I am using Windows 10 and Visual Studio Enterprise 2017

```
    Bundles.config:

                bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/Foundation-sites").Include(
                    "~/Content/foundation.*"));

                bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/foundation").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/foundation.cjs.js",
                    "~/Scripts/foundation.esm.js",
                    "~/Scripts/foundation.js",
                    "~/Scripts/foundation.min.js"));
            }

    _Layout.cshtml:

        @Styles.Render("~/Content/foundation")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/foundation")
```

I then added some html to the About view, (Created and tested standalone with Foundation page generated with node js, Foundation new etc;)
Just with a simple flex grid and a few other simple tags.

I am a newbie, so I think I may be missing something very obvious, but the Foundation CSS is not being applied, and Grid is not working (or other styles), Any ideas would be gratefully received.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the correct way to do it, but adding the following to _layout.cshtml did the trick:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/foundation.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/foundation.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/foundation-float.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/foundation-float.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/foundation-prototype.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/foundation-prototype.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/foundation-rtl.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/foundation-rtl.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/Site.css">
```

Comment: Did you mean to post this with a new/separate account? If not, you can use the Contact Us link at the bottom of the page to request your accounts be merged.